# creating a dll using C++/CLI

Tags: .net, dll, c++-cli

I have a c++ code(DLL).

I would like to convert it to managed c++ code to be used in DLL.

Then, it can call it from any .Net managed code..

Is it possible to create a dll from managed c++ , if not  what other alternative options?

My goal is creating a portable lib that can be used by any one .

Comment: You probably want to replace "managed C++" with "C++/CLI" in your question, tile and tags. "Managed Extensions for C++" (the full name for "managed C++") was replaced by "C++/CLI" in 2005.

Comment: Please note: for the code to be fully usable by .Net callers, you need to use .Net types in your interface. You probably want to create a wrapper to marshal the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, in CLR tab you have a **Class Library** template for create DLL in **C++/CLI**.

Comment: so, is that mean yes for my question